# Can multiple custom checkin policies for TFS be in the same assembly?

Tags: version-control, tfs, customization

I am implementing multiple custom checkin policies for TFS and I am wondering if they all need to be in the same assembly or if I have to put each one in its own assembly.

Comment: I think it would be easier to have them in one assembly if they are all related and will be deployed as a whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter.  As long as they implement the appropriate base class and implement the interfaces.

See [Create Custom Check-in Policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx)